# creating a dropdownlist with asp with C# addbutton command

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im trying to create a dropdownlist with asp. Once the user clicks on the dropdownlist, he should be able to select plus or minus sign. for some reason the code is not working. Can someone tell me what is going on.

TextBox Example

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

    <script runat="server">
        protected void AddButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int Answer;
            if(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "+")

                     {Answer = Convert.ToInt32(Value1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(Value2.Text);
                     AnswerMessage.Text = Answer.ToString();}

            else if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "-")
                   {
                    Answer = Convert.ToInt32(Value1.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(Value2.Text);
                    AnswerMessage.Text = Answer.ToString();
                   }


        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <h3> TextBox Example </h3>
    <p>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Value1" Columns="2" MaxLength="3" Text="1" runat="server"/>
        +<select id="Select1">
            <option></option>

            </select>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">

               <asp:ListItem Text="Default text" Value="Default value" />
                 <asp:ListItem Text="+"  > +   </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem  Text="-"  > - </asp:ListItem>


            </asp:DropDownList>


        <asp:TextBox ID="Value2" Columns="2" MaxLength="3" Text="1" runat="server"/>
        =
        <asp:Label ID="AnswerMessage" runat="server"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <asp:Button ID="AddButton" Text="Add" OnClick="AddButton_Click" runat="server"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Value1RequiredValidator" ControlToValidate="Value1"
             ErrorMessage="Please enter a value.<br />" Display="Dynamic"
             runat="server"/>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Value2RequiredValidator" ControlToValidate="Value2"
             ErrorMessage="Please enter a value.<br />" Display="Dynamic"
             runat="server"/>
        <asp:RangeValidator ID="Value1RangeValidator" ControlToValidate="Value1"
             Type="Integer" MinimumValue="1" MaximumValue="100" Display="Dynamic"
             ErrorMessage="Please enter an integer <br /> between than 1 and 100.<br />"
             runat="server"/>
        <asp:RangeValidator ID="Value2RangeValidator" ControlToValidate="Value2"
             Type="Integer" MinimumValue="1" MaximumValue="100" Display="Dynamic"
             ErrorMessage="Please enter an integer <br /> between than 1 and 100.<br />"    
             runat="server"/>
    </p>

      <asp:scriptmanager id="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/>


  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if statement should have "==" that is you if statement should read " if  (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "+")"

Comment: ok, i have the changes, but the program still does not work, for some reason the code will not reach the inner part of the if block

Comment: did you debug and see what value you are getting for "DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text" ? if yes what was it?

Answer (score 0):

there are couple of issues

1. your HTML is not properly formatted, the drop down list should be outside your select tag

> ```
> <select id="Select1">
>    <option></option>
>  </select>
>
>  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
>       <asp:ListItem Text="Default text" Value="Default value" />
>       <asp:ListItem text="+"></asp:ListItem>
>       <asp:ListItem text ="-"></asp:ListItem>
>  </asp:DropDownList>
> ```

1. Set + and - sign as Text property of your ListItem
2. your If statement inside button click event should have "==" operator instead of "="